# How to use app.config file with mstest.exe in cruise control

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I am using mstest.exe for executing my test cases, when i run this test cases from vs they run fine, but when i run them from cruise control using ms-build they give me exception that they are not able to read application.config.
I mean i have created a class that reads value from app.config.
It has a field that read port number as a string and convert it to int, with VS it is working file, but with Ms build it show exception that ArgumentNullException.

So how can i specify that mstest use specific app.config file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On the app.config properties, set `Copy to Output Directory`=`Copy always`

If the tests run under the `TestDeploymentDir` use the [`DeploymentItemAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx):

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("app.config")]
```

In Visual Studio 2012 or newer you can use [`.runsettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) for more deployment options.

In Visual Studio 2010:

From the `Test` menu > `Edit Test Settings` > `Local` > `Deployment` tab > check `Enable deployment` and `Add file` and point the app.config

Comment: Hmm the Edit Test Settings menu item seems to be missing in VS 2013

Comment: @MatthewLock that was for VS 2010, I've updated the answer for VS 2012 or newer